# Is a member interface in a class declaration implicitly public?

Tags: java, jls

**Code**

I have the following class with a member interface:

```
package com.example.withinterface;

public class SomeClass {

    interface SomeInterface {

        void doSomething();
    }
}
```

And another class trying to access it:

```
package com.example.withinterface.main;

import com.example.withinterface.SomeClass;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] argss) {
        System.out.println(SomeClass.SomeInterface.class);
    }
}
```

**Error**

In Main I get the following error from javac: `SomeInterface is not public in SomeClass; cannot be accessed from outside package`.

And in Eclipse: `SomeInterface is not public in SomeClass; cannot be accessed from outside package`.

Both compiling as Java 7. Everything compiles fine if I make SomeInterface `public`.

**But Spec says**

The [Java Language Specification for Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5) says this:

> A member interface is an interface whose declaration is directly
> enclosed in another class or interface declaration.
>
> A member interface in a class declaration is implicitly public (§6.6)
> unless an access modifier is specified.

The [Java Language Specification for Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.5) doesn't seem to have the second sentence.

**Question**

So shouldn't SomeInterface be considered public and shouldn't Main compile?

**Update**

As suggested by [Ajay George](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638627/is-a-member-interface-in-a-class-declaration-implicitly-public/11639010#11639010) this was indeed [an error in the Java Language Specification 7](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7186836) (thanks [JamesB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638627/is-a-member-interface-in-a-class-declaration-implicitly-public/11639010#comment15475534_11639010)). In the meantime the spec was corrected and the incorrect sentence removed. [Last version in Archive.org with the incorrect sentence](http://web.archive.org/web/20130123161047/http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5).

Comment: Huh. I always assumed everything was package protected unless otherwise stated. I guess I learned something new.

Comment: I think this is because memeber that don't have an access modifier are having package-access. So they cannot be used by other packages

Comment: @Desolator Did you read the question? Member interfaces are **public by default**.

Comment: My question is, what on Earth made them introduce this change?? Now there's no more package-level member interfaces.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You mean we can't do something like `protected interface Foo`? Or am I wrong in assuming that would do the desired thing?

Comment: @DennisMeng Well, `protected` is not the same as package-private. There is no keyword to specify it.

Comment: \*shrug\* Noted. Having the ability to have package-private things would be nice.

Comment: @DennisMeng Try this code out using Java 7 JDK and you will see that the JLS must be wrong as the code only compiles if the member interface is declared public. Hence, package-level member interfaces remain.

Comment: I'll take your word for it for now; I'm still using Java 6 at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the spec is wrong .
Here is the javap output with your code.

```
E:\workspace>javap com\example\withinterface\SomeClass
Warning: Binary file com\example\withinterface\SomeClass contains com.example.wi
thinterface.SomeClass
Compiled from "SomeClass.java"
public class com.example.withinterface.SomeClass {
  public com.example.withinterface.SomeClass();
}

E:\workspace>javap com\example\withinterface\SomeClass$SomeInterface
Warning: Binary file com\example\withinterface\SomeClass$SomeInterface contains
com.example.withinterface.SomeClass$SomeInterface
Compiled from "SomeClass.java"
interface com.example.withinterface.SomeClass$SomeInterface {
  public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

I changed the interface to public and then recompiled it.

```
E:\workspace>javap com\example\withinterface\SomeClass
Warning: Binary file com\example\withinterface\SomeClass contains com.example.wi
thinterface.SomeClass
Compiled from "SomeClass.java"
public class com.example.withinterface.SomeClass {
  public com.example.withinterface.SomeClass();
}

E:\workspace>javap com\example\withinterface\SomeClass$SomeInterface
Warning: Binary file com\example\withinterface\SomeClass$SomeInterface contains
com.example.withinterface.SomeClass$SomeInterface
Compiled from "SomeClass.java"
public interface com.example.withinterface.SomeClass$SomeInterface {
  public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

Note the difference in the Inner class.

Comment: I agree. The JLS is obviously wrong. Using Java 7 JDK, the code only compiles if the member interface is **explicitly** declared public.

Comment: @JamesB No, the spec **cannot** by definition be wrong. What is wrong is the implementation. JLS is not descriptive, but **prescriptive**.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it does look like a typo: *" A member interface in **a class** declaration is implicitly public"* should probably be *" A member interface in **an interface** declaration is implicitly public"*. It would make sense in the context of the previous sentence: *" enclosed in another class or interface declaration"*.

Comment: @assylias Well noted. Although it still doesn't make JLS wrong---it makes all implementations wrong :) I do hope they will rectify this. Where do isssues like this get posted? Maybe it has already been raised.

Comment: BTW [it would not be the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661210/errata-for-java-language-specification-3rd-edition).

Comment: @assylias Heh heh, already reading it :) There's the link to JSR 901, but still not helpful...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have raised this issue with Oracle by email. I used the info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/feedback.html

Comment: @JamesB Would love to know their response on this.

Comment: OK, some typo in the JLS then. Great idea to use javap for this :-)

Comment: @assylias Yes, probably a mistake or typo. But member types of interfaces are already discussed in the [JLS section 9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5)

Comment: @AjayGeorge Alex Buckley at Oracle has replied and a bug has been logged. When it is publicly available, I will post a link here.